# Calling a method at set intervals from the server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm writing some code, where after calling the GetRoomAvailability() from the mvc action method, and then returns a view (MVC) to the client. The method create a new  threading.timer class in order to call the _repository.roomsAavailability() every 50 minutes. I want this timer to continue to call this repository on a background thread,  without me having to call GetRoomAvaibility() again every 50 minutes, on a UI thread. How can I do this? At the moment

```
public void GetRoomAvailability()
{
    // checl for room availability every 30 minutes
    Timer timer = new Timer((e) =>
    {
        _repository.RoomAvailability();

        if (true)
        {
            // write some code to see if values have been changes since last time
            //_hub.ClientsUpdateRoomsAvailability();
        }

    }, null, 0, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0.5).Milliseconds);
}
```

this is only being called once, when calling the GetRoomAvailability().

Comment: you might want to have a look on somethinkg like SignalR http://www.asp.net/signalr to get the data real time rather than using a timer...

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a `Timer` and try to do this yourself. [There are many pitfalls](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/).

Instead, use a package like [Quartz.NET](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) to set up a recurring background task background. [This Scott Hanselman article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx) gives examples and more detail.

Don't forget, you will need to set IIS to keep your application alive. If you are writing this for shared hosting, it's a non-starter.

Comment: Thanks.  Based on your references, I manage to get this working using Quartz.net

Answer (score 0):

You are not keeping a reference to the timer after the method is finished, my guess is that the timer is getting disposed by the garbage collector since theres no reference to it